# URLSession.shared.dataTask issues

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession

so having some issues with creating a `URLSession` in Swift 3 referencing the `dataTask`. I am getting this error and do not understand why:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'

```
func fetchVideos() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/youtubeassets/home.json")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(str)

    // this resume function is not reading correctly either
    }.resume()

}
```

Comment: Your url should be `URL` instead of `NSURL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3, you should not use the `NS`-prefixed types, when there is a native Swift type available. For example, instead of `NSURL`, use `URL`, and instead of Objective-C's `NSString`, use `String`. Generally, try to use [Swift-Foundation](http://swiftdoc.org) as much as possible.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/youtubeassets/home.json")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str)

}.resume()
```